# How to use 'coproc' to interact with another command driven program

Tags: bash, coproc

Ok, obviously I am NOT a bash guru and am in need of one!

I have never used 'coproc' before, but it seems to be just what I need.  But, I have to admit that I can not extrapolate from the various 'ping' examples out there!  [I did try for a couple of hours...]

All I want to do is to start a 'coproc' shell script that can take input from standard in and writes it's results to standard out.  I want the main script to do the sending and processing of those commands and results respectively.

Here is one of the simplest outlines of what I am trying to do:
**EDITED WITH BETTER DETAIL**

```
#! /bin/bash

coproc bkgndProc {
    /some/path/to/usefulScript.sh  maybeSomeArgsHere
}

// send command #1 to bkgndProc here
result=$(echo 'command' <&${bkgndProc[0]})    ### Doesn't work for me
echo "Did it work? $result"   ### this just prints back the 'command' I used

// here execute conditional logic based on result:
// if result1; then
//     send command #2 here, getting results
// else
//     send command #3 here, again getting results
// fi
```

Sorry about using pseudo-code above, but I'm not sure what those sending commands should be! If anyone could supply the details that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
result = $(echo 'command' <&${bkgndProc[0]})    ### Doesn't work for me
```

wouldn't work at least basically since you have spaces on it

```
result=$(echo 'command' <&${bkgndProc[0]})
```

---- Update ----

A simple concept could be shown in a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# create the co-process
coproc myproc {
    bash
}

# send a command to it (echo a)
echo 'echo a' >&"${myproc[1]}"

# read a line from its output
read line <&"${myproc[0]}"

# show the line
echo "$line"
```

Outputs:

```
a
```

Another which reads multiple lines using a timeout:

```
#!/bin/bash

coproc myproc {
    bash
}

# send a command to message 4 random numbers in 4 lines
echo 'echo "$RANDOM"; echo "$RANDOM"; echo "$RANDOM"; echo "$RANDOM"' >&"${myproc[1]}"

# keep reading the line until it times out
while read -t 1 -u "${myproc[0]}" line; do
    echo "$line"
done
```

Output:

```
17393
1423
8368
1782
```

If we use `cat`, it would no longer quit since the other end is still alive and connected, and EOF is not yet reached. It's the reason why we used timeouts.

```
cat <&"${myproc[0]}"
```

Comment: Good point, but I did not have that white space in the actual code I tried.  Edited the post and cleaned that up.

Comment: @Aleks-DanielJakimenko - yes you are right, I had 'real' code which I could not post.  I should have taken the time to create a still real example that would illustrate my problem

Comment: @konsolebox - THANKS - the problem I had was in fact when I use the 'cat' as you mentioned.  There is existing output so that was the first thing I did, and never made it past that point!  Thanks also for a very clear, powerful, and simple example!